# Biology researcher survey?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've just checked the Stack Overflow's developer survey and it was quite interesting, and I was wondering if Biology has something similar like "Researchers Survey'. Or this thing is specific to SO, or only graduated sites have these things?

Comment: What developers survey was that? You could ask a question on Meta. I asked http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2668/4671 on unix.sx Stack Exchange.

Comment: this survey: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2015-the-results/?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a survey on Math or TeX so I don't think it has to do with a site being graduated. SO is the main SE site so they do/experiment/get things before many sites. Even if they do something, it doesn't mean another site will necessarily do it as well since each site is self governed.

Additionally, that survey came from the blog. I don't think every site is using their blog. For instance, if you go to math and click blog, you will be taken to the math site blog. However, if you go to the blog for biology, you will be taken to the SE blog where the survey is listed. This leads me to believe that biology is currently not using their blog.

If you want to construct the first blog, you can access the mods since they may need to activate it. Moreover, if you want it to be a survey, you can again volunteer to construct it if the mods okay (I say this on the presumption that they need to get the blog started for the site first).

Comment: thanks for the ideas I might as well do! I think the blog could be used to explain the very basic things of biology (as like a biology 101 course) so users with no experience could use it or be directed to learn the basics. Also propagation of good science is always welcomed, I think.